# Objectify Query Opposite of IN

Tags: java, database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, objectify

Suppose I have an entity kind called EntityA and I have a list of EntityA ids. How can I query all EntityA entities from my database which the id IS NOT in the list of EntityA ids that I have?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
ofy().load().type(EntityA.class).filter("!IN", entityAKeys);
```

How could I get it working? Is it possible?

Comment: can you try if NIN works?

Comment: Else it is exactly "NOT IN"

Comment: "Unknown operator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing like:

```
List<Key<MXChallenge>> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Key<MXChallenge>> searchInKeys = ofy().load().type(MXChallenge.class).keys().list();

for(Long id : alreadyRetrieved){
    keyList.add(Key.create(MXChallenge.class, id));
}

searchInKeys.removeAll(keyList);

QueryResultIterator<MXChallenge> iteratorChallenges = ofy().load()
        .type(MXChallenge.class).filter("colour", "blue").filterKey("IN", searchInKeys).iterator();
```

I'm nor sure in terms of performance though but as it is a "keys-only" operation I'd say it should be fine.

Comment: There's really no point in doing a `filterKey("IN"` - just load the keys themselves. `ofy().load().keys(searchInKeys)`.

Comment: It's cause in my real case I have more filters. I will update the answer to let it clear.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported as Cloud Datastore only allows queries supported by an index to ensure they don't break as they your dataset scales.

You will have to query for all entities in kind EntityA and filter out those in entityAKeys on the client side yourself.